# HttpClient with given Bearer token always returning 401(not authorized)

Tags: c#, .net, get, httpclient, bearer-token

I'm using HttpClient and for some reason its always giving me 401(not authorized) response while trying to call a GET with Bearer token. Here is my code:

```
try
        {
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);

            var strContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            return strContent;
        }
```

How to make it work, because with postman I've been putting the token and it always works but for some reason it doesn't in C#

Comment: Use a tool like Fiddler to examine both http requests (postman and c#) and play spot the difference. Once you've identified the difference, we can try to work out what the equivalent c# would be to match the postman version.

Comment: And/or show us the postman request (screenshots can be used, or export the request file from postman)

Comment: Tip: 1) [`HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8#examples) is intended to be instantiated once per application, rather than per-use. 2) `HttpResponseMessage` is `IDisposable` consider to decorate it with `using` or `Dispose()` it properly. 3) to check is request is succeessful, you may use either `response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()` to throw, or `respone.IsSuccessStatusCode` bool property. 4) `await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` instead of `.Result` is more safe here.